# Windows Scheduler - switch Task status to Fail

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm currently developping a C# program that will be run every hour via the Windows Task Scheduler.
I would like to know if there is a way for my program to return a specific value that will mark the task as failed if something went wrong.
I mean, do the Windows Task Scheduler expect certain type of return code when running a program?
 Something Like:
0 <=> Everything is OK
Any other Value <=> ERROR

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I think that it's more when you use the Task Scheduler API, and that allows you to get the task status.

Thank you for the Help!

Comment: as you stated, `Any other Value <=> ERROR`, why not just have your program return 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return an int value in your main method, that value will be displayed in the "Last run Result" in the Task Scheduler.

```
static int Main() {
    return -1;
}
```

That will show 0xffffffff in the task scheduler

You can also use the System logs to provide more details about the error

Answer (score 0):

I would just log the results to the Event Viewer. Then you can monitor it there with details.

[How to write to an event log by using Visual C#](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/307024)